# Time-driven Triggered Google Script to move Spreadsheet rows that meeting certain conditions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have this Google script and want to make it run every 12 hours, but the time-driven trigger setting doesn't work:

```
 function binIT() {

   var sheetOrg = "1stSheet";
   var columnNum = 4;
   var value1 = "DONE";
   var value2 = "Removed";
   var sheetBin = "2ndSheet";

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

   if (sheet.getName() == sheetOrg && range.getColumn() == columnNum && range.getValue() == value1) {
     var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetBin);
     var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
     sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
     sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
   }

   if (sheet.getName() == sheetOrg && range.getColumn() == columnNum && range.getValue() == value2) {
     var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetBin);
     var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
     sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
     sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
   }

 }
```

This is the email I get after a while:

> *Your script, Makro testing, has recently failed to finish
>   successfully. 
>   A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure
>   the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving
>   future failure notifications, click here.
>
> The script is used by the
>   document Event Discovery.
>
> Summary:
>
> Error Message Count
>
> Bad value (line 6,
>   file "Code")  2
>
> Details:
>
> Start Function    Error Message   Trigger End
>
> 10/28/15 5:22 PM  BinIT   Bad value (line 6, file
>   "Code")   time-based  10/28/15 5:22 PM
>
> 10/28/15 5:23 PM  BinIT   Bad value
>   (line 6, file "Code") time-based  10/28/15 5:23 PM
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Google
>
> Apps Script Need help? Visit the Google Apps Script documentation.
>
> Please do not reply to this message. (c) 2015 Google*

I notice that in the script I have, it seems to take the active cell as range and thus time trigger would not work. But I don't know how to scan through the whole column and get value

My java knowledge is close to none, so I do apologise if this is a silly concern. But I really need to get this to work for my google spreadsheet so I very much appreciate your help.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Many thanks and regards,

Nam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As been suggested already, you can't use getActiveRange() and getActiveSheet() on timedriven triggers. Instead try something like this (on a copy of your data, as it hasn't been tested). Don't forget to fill in your spreadsheetID in var ss...

```
function binIT() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YOUR_SPREADSHEETID_HERE'),
    sheetOrg = ss.getSheetByName("1stSheet"),
    sheetBin = ss.getSheetByName("2ndSheet"),
    valuesToCheck = ["DONE", "Removed"],
    arr = [], 
    values = sheetOrg.getDataRange().getValues(),
    i = values.length;
while (--i) {
if (valuesToCheck.indexOf(values[i][3]) > -1) {
        arr.unshift(values[i])
       sheetOrg.deleteRow(i + 1) 
     }
   }
sheetBin.getRange(sheetBin.getLastRow()+1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much @JPV .
Just a quick question, where do you define the column? Is it this part here **indexOf(values[i][3])** ? It says 3 but column D is actually being checked

Comment: Arrays in JS are zero-indexed. So the first column in the spreadsheet will be at index 0 in an JS array.